# Django: database 'postgres1' does not exist but it does actually

Tags: python, django, postgresql

`python manage.py migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "postgres1" does not exist
```

But I actually created the role and the database and granted, end everything is correct.

ok, then checking  `createdb postgres1`

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "postgres1" already exists
```

how should I understand that? Default postgres postgres configuration works, but no one of created databases work.

EDIT: more traceback:

```
     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/tick-tock/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "postgres1" does not exist
```

Settings.py:

```
 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'postgres1',
         'USER':'postgres',
         'PASSWORD':'',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
     }
 }
```

Comment: I believe you environemt leads `createdb` to one postgres instance while django works with the other

Comment: @VaoTsun please explain to me, two postgres installed on system?

Comment: probably, but not necessarily. show connection string for python?..

Comment: @VaoTsun added traceback with python connect line and settings.py database conf

Comment: if you dont use port - you use socket, but you use localhost here - it either ignores several keys or the whole config - right?..

Comment: @VaoTsun probably... I tried to use port 5432, error traceback is the same

Comment: @VaoTsun what is the possible solution ?

Comment: if `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres1` gives error and `psql postgres1` not, you have several local dbs, then run `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -c "create database postgres1"`

Comment: @VaoTsun  yeah, it's true.. could you give me a hint, how I can get rid of it and select right  one?

Comment: @VaoTsun and by the way, I didn't find any other postgres installed on the system